# ssm automation document input in AWS-RunShellScript not substituting variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm

I am trying to run a command in bash where part of the command is substituted from a variable that I created in a previous step, however the string substitution is not working.  I have tried many variations of this with single, double quotes, etc but cant not get it to work.

```
mainSteps:
  - name: getIps
    action: 'aws:invokeLambdaFunction'
    timeoutSeconds: 1200
    maxAttempts: 1
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
      FunctionName: Automation-GetIPs
      Payload: '{"asg": "Staging_web_ASG"}'
    outputs:
      - Name: asg_ips
        Selector: $.Payload.IPs
        Type: StringList
  - name: updatelsync
    action: 'aws:runCommand'
    timeoutSeconds: 1200
    inputs:
      DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
      InstanceIds:
        - '{{ InstanceID }}'
      Parameters:
        commands:
          - 'echo {{getIps.asg_ips}} > /root/asg_ips.test'
```

In the above code.  I set asg_ips in step1 who's OutputPayload is as follows :

```
{"Payload":{"IPs": ["172.xx.x.xxx", "172.xx.x.xxx"]},"StatusCode":200}
```

but for input in the 2nd step, it shows as follows...

```
{"commands":["echo {{getIps.asg_ips}} > /root/asg_ips.test"]}
```

I need to get it to show something like this...

```
{"commands":["echo ["172.xx.x.xxx", "172.xx.x.xxx"] > /root/asg_ips.test"]}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference for you use of the `outputs` in `aws:invokeLambdaFunction`? There is no such field in [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-lamb.html). Thus if you do `'echo {{getIps.Payload}} > /root/asg_ips.test'` it will work, but obviously will need to process the asg_ips.test file to get the ip values from full Payload.

Comment: That looks to be my problem.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: Hi. Just wondering how did it go?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by incorrect use of `outputs` in [aws:invokeLambdaFunction](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-lamb.html) SSM action. Specifically, the lambda action does not have `outputs` attribute as shown in the linked documentation:

```
name: invokeMyLambdaFunction
action: aws:invokeLambdaFunction
maxAttempts: 3
timeoutSeconds: 120
onFailure: Abort
inputs:
  FunctionName: MyLambdaFunction
```

In contrast, as a side note, `outputs` attribute is valid in [aws:executeAwsApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/automation-action-executeAwsApi.html).

Therefore, the solution is to **directly refer** to the `Payload` returned by the lambda action:

```
mainSteps:
  - name: getIps
    action: 'aws:invokeLambdaFunction'
    timeoutSeconds: 1200
    maxAttempts: 1
    onFailure: Abort
    inputs:
      FunctionName: Automation-GetIPs
      Payload: '{"asg": "Staging_web_ASG"}'
  - name: updatelsync
    action: 'aws:runCommand'
    timeoutSeconds: 1200
    inputs:
      DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
      InstanceIds:
        - '{{ InstanceID }}'
      Parameters:
        commands:
          - 'echo {{getIps.Payload}} > /root/asg_ips.test'
```

The side effect is that now `asg_ips.test` needs to be **post-processed** to get the IP ranges values.